# List to CSV writing is not working in Python 2.7

Tags: list, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I have converted my python3 code to python2 using the module 3to2 and now am not able to write to CSV file.

`TypeError: must be unicode, not str`
After the conversion code

```
 def writeCSV(self,filepath,data):
        with open(filepath, u'a', newline=u'') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(data)
```

The data which is passed is ['10/06/2020 04:28:57 AM', u'HCL Docker', u'Down']
. May I know how can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the list:

```
['10/06/2020 04:28:57 AM', u'HCL Docker', u'Down']
```

The first item, as the error message says, must be `unicode`, not `str`. As you can see, Unicode is prefixed with `u`, like this: `u'HCL Docker'`.

So you should make sure that each item in `data` is `unicode`. You can convert everything to `unicode` like this:

```
writer.writerow(map(unicode, data))
```

Comment: I have already tried this But it will result in the same outcome

Comment: Changed as [u'10/06/2020 13:14:43 PM', u'HCL Docker', u'Down']